# Symfony2 & Doctrine2 PDOException without description

Tags: exception, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I wanted to use this code, and it break on flush() without any exception message:

```
1. at PDOStatement ->execute (null) 
in ../vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php at line 131    
2. at Statement ->execute () 
in ../vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php at line 237    
3. at BasicEntityPersister ->executeInserts () 
in ../vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php at line 726    
4. at UnitOfWork ->executeInserts (object(ClassMetadata)) 
in ../vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php at line 292    
5. at UnitOfWork ->commit () 
in ../vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php at line 334    
6. at EntityManager ->flush () 
in ../src/Tools/TFIBundle/Model/CSVImport.php at line 136    
7. at CSVImport ->addCategory ('fundusz obligacji') 
in ../src/Tools/TFIBundle/Model/CSVImport.php at line 114
```

addCategory() method looks:

```
public function addCategory( $categoryName )
{
    $category = new Category();
    $category->setName( $categoryName );

    $this->em->persist( $category );
    $this->em->flush();
    $this->counter['category']++;

    return $category;
}
```

any idea what is wrong? or how to get PDOException message within symfony2 ?

Comment: Are you sure you are running in development mode?

Comment: Maybe the message is hidden in your html page source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem just seconds ago. It got fixed when I went to the production mode and and closed the session. It looks like development mode has problems with sessions when you do things like replacing the entire folder with a lot of changes while session still alive.

Try clearing your session, it may work.

Comment: this not worked at all, but I've found some error in my code that caused this problem. thanks for effort.